# Assetic and domain folder

Tags: symfony

I'm using Assetic to manage assets in my Symfony2 project. It worked well before i made my application accessible with a domain folder.

```
before : myapplication.local    // Assetic works

now    : mydomain.local/myapplication    // Assetic doesn't work
```

The requested css files are called but the filter cssrewrite writes a wrong path for the ressources.

> Error : 
>   NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mydomain.local/Resources/public/images/menu/nav-bg-1.png
>
> The expected URL should looks like http://www.mydomain.local/myapplication/Resources/public/images/menu/nav-bg-1.png

Here is my Assetic Call

```
{% block stylesheets %}
     {% stylesheets
         '@Mybundle/Resources/public/css/myfile.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
     {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I know Assetic say to not use the `@`-naming when using cssrewrite. But it worked fine without the domain folder, and using "bundles/mybundle/css/myfile.css" does not solve the problem.

If you need anymore information, just ask me ;).

Thank you for your time and you help.

Comment: have you called `cache:clear` and `assets:install`?

Comment: Yes, both of them but nothing changed

Comment: even if you reverted to the required notation which doesn't use the `@`? Which exact version do you use?

Comment: The path is still the same when i don't use @ - naming.
I'm using assetic 2.3 with symfony 2.6

Answer (score 1):

You should use naming without `@` as said in the documentation. Also you need to dump your assets via assetic every time you change anything with them.

To dump assetic run next command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

or

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod // To generate only files needed for production environment
```

Comment: The probleme is still the same, the path is now http://www.mydomain.local/bundles/mybundle/css/myfile.png and still missing the "/myapplication" between the domain and "/bundles". I had the same thing when i tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fixe this issue by removing the cssrewrite filter and putting all my images, fonts, etc... in web/images or web/fonts, etc... Then in my css, all my path are like "../folder/file"

Comment: Do you still use the assetic?

Comment: Yes Assetic is still running

Answer (score 0):

You can define the [assets base URL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls) in your <kbd>app/config/config*.yml</kbd> files:

In `dev` environment: <kbd>app/config/config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_base_urls:
            http: [http://www.mydomain.local/myapplication/]
```

In `prod` environment:  <kbd>app/config/config_prod.yml</kbd>

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_base_urls:
            http: [http://www.example.com/static/]
```

The `cssrewrite` filter should remove `Resources/public/` from the URL.